# Building a lexer that reads character by character?

Tags: php, lexer

I'm building a basic lexer in PHP, just as an exercise. Right now I'm making it lex PHP source and output highlighted source via HTML tags, but I'm using real token names and stuff, not just a few broad regex matches.

The way I'm setting it up is to read in the PHP source, character by character. It checks the current character to figure out what the current token *might* be and then reads in the next *x* characters that match the appropriate pattern.

For example, if the current character is a ", I'll read in all characters until I encounter another " which wasn't preceded by an escaping \. Is this a bad way of doing it? The only other way I've seen and understood involved making a class that compiled a massive regex and matched all tokens at once, but that doesn't seem as flexible to me.

Thoughts?

```
    $str = '';

    $php = str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $php );
    $php = str_split( $php );
    $len = count( $php );
    $keyword = '';

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++ ) {
        $char = $php[$i];

        // Detect PHP strings and backtick execution operators
        if ( strpos( self::STRING_CHARACTERS, $char ) !== FALSE ) {
            $string         = $char;
            $opening_quote  = $char;
            $escaped        = FALSE;

            while ( isset( $php[++$i] ) && ( $escaped || $php[$i] != $opening_quote ) ) {
                $string .= $php[$i];

                if ( $php[$i] == '\\' ) {
                    $escaped = !$escaped;
                }
            }

            $string .= $php[$i];

            if ( $opening_quote == "'" ) {
                $str .= '<span class="php-string php-single-quoted-string">' . htmlspecialchars( $string ) . '</span>';
            } else if ( $opening_quote == '"' ) {
                $str .= '<span class="php-string php-double-quoted-string">' . htmlspecialchars( $string ) . '</span>';
            } else if ( $opening_quote == '`' ) {
                $str .= '<span class="php-execution-operator php-backtick">' . htmlspecialchars( $string ) . '</span>';
            }
            continue;
        }

        $str .= $char;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're intending to keep it a hand-written tool, then definitely keep going with you current approach.

The giant matching engine approach is fantastic if you're writing a tool such as `flex` or ANTLR, and you want to be able to build highly efficient parsers all day long for a variety of languages. But it is a fair amount of extra effort if you're interested in parsing only one language.

Answer (score 1):

A typical handwritten approach would be to create a list of regex or automata.  You run down the list and the first element that successfully matches from your current possition in the input, gives you the next token and classification. You can speed it up a little by using a map that limits the list by the current character.

If you want to get fancier, you can combine automata into one giant one, but typically a tool is used for that.

You might be interested in the free Stanford compiler course offered by https://class.coursera.org/.